# FBConnect “via” link broken on feed posts from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

I posted this on regular SO before I found the Facebook-specific one, so hopefully it will get some more love here.

I have an iOS app that is successfully posting to Facebook via the FBConnect SDK. I have registered the app in Facebook as a native iPhone app and filled out the required data (bundle ID, app store id, etc), however I am running into one small, but very annoying issue.

When the app posts to the user's feed, the message has a "via App Name" link that presumably goes to the app store, or somewhere sensible. This link never work, it always goes to a page stating "Page not found", with no helpful information.

The link is of the form: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=${app.id}

I have verified that the ID that it is putting in there is in fact my app ID. Can anyone shed some light on what might be causing this and some possible fixes?

Comment: nickbona, can you comment on how you were able to solve this, step by step?  I have same issue for native iOS app.  I would like "via" link to go directly to itunes appstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the website config setting for your application.  See this for an example:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=204143816348127

Notice facebook displays a message about redirecting the user to a landing page.  You need to define a landing page in your app settings for it to use.  Otherwise it can't go there.

Comment: Where is that configured? On the app page, I do not see any such field when I have native iPhone app selected as the type of app.

Comment: To be more specific, under "Basic Info" I see App Display Name:
App Namespace:
Contact Email:
App Domain:. And under "Native iOS App" I have: iOS Bundle ID:
iPhone App Store ID:
iPad App Store ID:
Configured for iOS SSO:
URL Scheme Suffix:
Category:

Comment: One more bit. Next to "iPhone App Store Id" there is a link for "Go to App Store" once the field is filled out, presumably to test the ID, and this in fact works just fine.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Web Site` url in the settings?  See also https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/

Comment: "Website url" does not appear on the page when the app type is Native iOS App.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, but please note that you need to go to the "Advanced" section of the settings to configure this.

Comment: Hi Nickbona, what did you do in advanced section?  Can you tell me exact info you had to setup for native app?  I'm seeing same issue as you did.

Answer (score 1):

It's in Settings/Basic put your URL in the Website and Mobile Web section.

I a normal browser it will use the "Website" url on a mobile platform (iOS, Android, etc) it should use "Mobile Web" url.